# AWS Route traffic to two load balancer simultaneously

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, elastic-load-balancer

I have a requirements to record all incoming and outgoing traffic to my application loadbalancer. I have a tool from F5 (install in EC2) to receive the traffic and process and perform actions (So I can setup ELB+ASG for this). However I want the traffic should go to the web server (Apache+PHP), so that my application also will work well.

I know GuardDuty and VPC flow logs are some alternate. But there are some limitation (It didn't capture all events comes to EC2 instance). Hence I need to rely some third party tools such as F5, checkpoint.

Regards
Senthil